# User control within another user control gets garbage collected in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, viewmodel, datacontext

I have a window with a menu and content control. When I load up a module it checks to see if that module is already open, if not it creates it, adds it to a collection of modules and makes it the current active one. They are setup like this

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
private void ChangeViewModel(Object parameter)
{
    string name = (string) parameter;

    IPageViewModel page;

    if (PageViewModels.FirstOrDefault(vm => vm.Name == name) != null)
    {
        CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels
            .FirstOrDefault(vm => vm.Name == name);
    }
    else
    {
        if (name == "TimeSheets")
        {
            page = new TimeSheetViewModel();
        }
        else if (name == "Test")
        {
             page = new TestViewModel();
        }
        else
        {
            page = new HomeViewModel();
        }

        CurrentPageViewModel = page;
        PageViewModels.Add(page);
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HomeViewModel}">
        <local:Home />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TimeSheetViewModel}">
        <local:Timesheet />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestViewModel}">
        <local:Test />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="gridContent" Margin="70,42,20,20" >
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
</Grid>
```

This seems to work for switching between modules/pages, but on one page I have a user control that has its own datacontext and this gets garbage collected anytime I leave this page and gets re-instantiated when I go back to the page.

TimeSheet.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <local:EmployeeList />
</Grid>
```

EmployeeList.xaml

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:EmployeeListViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource LIGHT_Main}"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Search "/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SearchParameter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="4,0,4,0"/>
        <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/Icons/SearchTiny.png" Margin="5,0,8,0"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="6">
        <DataGrid x:Name="gridEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeesFiltered}" MaxHeight="500"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource GridLines}" VerticalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource GridLines}" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="200"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Badge" Binding="{Binding Badge}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="1*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

So when it loads up I can search the list of employees which works fine, but as soon as I load up a different module the garbage collector takes away my search parameter and list of employees so it has to reload them. If I make EmployeeList.xaml's datacontext the same as TimeSheet.xaml's and add the required fields I don't lose my search parameter when switching between modules, but EmployeeList is a control I'd like to use in multiple places in my program so it would be nice to have it's own datacontext.

Let me know if this doesn't make sense, or my approach is all wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: A UserControl should not have a "private" view model, i.e. explicitly set its own DataContext. While that usually breaks any DataContext-based bindings of its properties, your issue seems to reveal another reason why you just shouldn't do it.

Comment: @Clemens , so then I have to add the fields SearchParameter and EmployeesFiltered to every ViewModel that I want to use an EmployeeList on? That doesn't seem right to me. What's the best method for making a user control that I can re-use throughout the entire program?

Comment: The UserControl should have bindable properties, i.e. dependency properties that are bound to view model properties. It would thus be independent of any particular view model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not of the view that all controls should necessarily have their own VMs. I generally code that a page has a VM and those values are passed to individual dependency properties on the control(s).

If you have data which needs to be shared between multiple controls, then that data should exist on only one VM and passed in as dependency property(ies) as such.

---

But...as an aside, I would have these VMS as properties on the main VM and each of the controls datacontext does automatically inherit its parents datacontext.... Which at this point to get the right data to each control would then become an exercise in binding (pathing) to the right location on the originating VM.

Comment: My goal is not to share data between the different instances of EmployeeList. I'd like to be able to use it in multiple places without having to put code in each view model for the fields that EmployeeList.xaml binds to. If I ever need to add another binding to EmployeeList, maybe a filter for Supervisor, then I'd have to go to every view that EmployeeList is used in and add that field to its ViewModel. Maybe I'm going about the whole MVVM process in the wrong way?